# Cant find SPWeb property that relates to "Add new pages to navigation automatically" in the navigation settings

Tags: 2013, navigation

I must be missing something but I cant find what property relates to this in the SPWeb member properties.

The property is represented by a checkbox, so I know its a boolean, and the field is described in the navigation settings page as "Add new pages to navigation automatically ".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
// Web Navigation
using (var site = new SPSite("http://yoursite/"))
{
 using (var web= site.OpenWeb())
 {
    // PublishingWeb Navigation
    var pubWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);

    // Exclude subsites to appear in navigation
    pubWeb.Navigation.CurrentIncludeSubSites = false;
    // Exclude new pages to appear in navigation
    pubWeb.Navigation.CurrentIncludePages = false;
    // Maximum number of dynamic levels
    pubWeb.Navigation.CurrentDynamicChildLimit = 20;

    pubWeb.Update();
 }
}
```

Reference:

[Programmatically set navigation settings in SharePoint 2013](http://tech.bool.se/programmatically-set-navigation-settings-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: The code you wrote isnt quite what I was looking for, but the link you provided helped.

Answer (score 0):

It's using the `SPWeb.Navigation.TopNavigationBar`

Excerpt from MSDN:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost"))
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                if (web.Navigation.UseShared) 
                    return; 

                // Get the top link bar.
                SPNavigationNodeCollection topnav = web.Navigation.TopNavigationBar;

                // Iterate over the collection of subsites.
                foreach (SPWeb subweb in web.Webs)
                {
                    // Check for an existing link.
                    SPNavigationNode node = web.Navigation.GetNodeByUrl(subweb.ServerRelativeUrl);
                    if (node == null || node.ParentId != 1002)
                    {
                        // No link, so add one.

                        // Truncate a long title.
                        string linkTitle = subweb.Title;
                        if (linkTitle.Length > 15)
                            linkTitle = linkTitle.Substring(0, 12) + "...";

                        // Create the link.
                        node = new SPNavigationNode(linkTitle, subweb.ServerRelativeUrl);

                        // Add it to the top link bar.
                        node = topnav.AddAsLast(node);
                    }
                    subweb.Dispose();
                }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg277254(v=office.14).aspx